# Catching PyGTK RuntimeWarning on gtk.Builder.connect_signals

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

gtk.Builder.connect_signals() issues a RuntimeWarning when a signal handler is not present:

```
__init__.py:16: RuntimeWarning: missing handler 'on_window_destroy'
  self.builder.connect_signals(self)
```

How do I keep it from issuing the warning and handle it myself?

**I'd like the warning to not be printed** (without requiring the user to pipe it to /dev/null)

Note: I'm not asking what the warning means, rather how to handle the Warning sort of *as if it were an exception*, at the moment, it seems a message to stderr is the only thing that happens, I can't do much with that in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [the `warnings` module](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings).

However, in this case I think it would be easier to check the return value of `connect_signals`. From [the documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/2.22/class-gtkbuilder.html#method-gtkbuilder--connect-signals):

> Also, if there is at least one such missing handler, `connect_signals` will return a list of their names, else return value is None.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, can't believe I never saw the warning module. However, I've clarified the question now; I'd like to not see the warning that pygtk prints automatically.

Comment: I've worked it out, I now use `warnings` to make warning exceptions and just catch them - thanks loads!